# How can I increase the text size in empathy chat windows?

Tags: 10.04, empathy, accessibility

The text that appears in empathy chat windows is quite small, even though I have set the font DPI to a large value in Preferences > Appearance. There does not appear to be any option to make this larger so that I can read what other people are sending me easily. I've been using pidgin in the meantime because it is a little better in this respect.

I would be grateful for any tips on how to increase the text size in empathy chat windows, even if this involves clever .gtkrc-2.0 hacks. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empathy uses adium themes, so what you would need to do is install/edit an adium theme to make the text larger.

Links:

- http://live.gnome.org/Empathy/Themes
- http://trac.adium.im/wiki/CreatingMessageStyles

Comment: The first link was the most useful for me. It provides a list of some empathy themes. The *.AdiumMessageStyle files are installed simply by copying them into ~/.local/share/adium/message-styles/.